# How to hide AppleTVs from the phone speaker options?

Tags: iphone, appletv, ios

Is there any way to remove AppleTV from the speaker list on the Phone app in iOS? I am running iOS 13.1. I tried disabling *Allow calls on other devices* but that did not solve the issue.

In the pic below, I want only the iPhone and Speaker as options
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off air play on the apple tv.

Otherwise the only way is to place the apple tv or iphone on different networks.  This can be done by creating a vlan and a new essid that tags network traffic to that vlan. Plus routing rules to give the vlan network access to things it needs (internet).

Or possibly create a new subnet and setup routing so the 2 subnets cannot communicate but still allows Internet access.

Comment: How do I disable AirPlay on the AppleTV?